# ¿Cómo corregir este error 404 en IIS?

Tags: laravel, iis

Estoy subiendo mi proyecto Laravel a IIS pero me arroja un error 404.
Cabe recalcar que intento acceder al sitio por IP publica pero tengo otros proyectos que no son con Laravel y a ellos si puedo acceder, esta es la url http://187.190.108.86:14500/nas y por ejemplo http://187.190.108.86:14500/seac es un sitio que sin problema accedo, alguien sabe como subir el proyecto correctamente?

[image: 1]Este es el eror que arroja, cabe mencionar que la carpeta Storage, Vendor y Cache de Bootstrap ya tienen permisos de IIS_IUSRS.

[image: 2]Aqui muestro que la ruta a la carpeta fisica apunta a la carpeta public del proyecto Laravel.

[image: 3]Y por ultimo estas son las reglas de reescritura de URL

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Creo que, sin ver cómo está configurado el servidor y qué intentas exponer, es imposible saber por qué IIS no encuentra los recursos. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).